# How do I add product short description on the product list template page on Magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I want to add product short description to product list template page, and I found this article: 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-3-magento-controller-dispatch

it said: `Blocks refer directly back to the models for their data. In other words, the Action Controller does not pass them a data structure.`
So , does it mean the code to get short description should be added to the Block class? But the Block class is Magento Core class: 
`Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List` 
I should not edit this class, right? So what should I do? Create my own Block class extend `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List` and add the showProductShortDescription method to it? If yes, Should I create my own module?

Thank you!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use in the list.phtml file this.

```
$_product->getShortDescription();
```

but Magento does not load all the attributes on the product listing page. 
Go to the admin pannel Catalog->Attributes-> Manage Attributes and edit the short description attribute.

Set “Used in product listing” to “Yes”. Save and clear the cache.